# how to Querying Morph To Relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

Trying to query [Polymorphic](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-morph-to-relationships) in laravel 8 with help of document but its showing me error

```
BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method App\Models\Product::keywordable()
```

here is my Models

Keyword.php

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Product::class, 'keywordable');
    }
```

Product.php

```
 public function keywords()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Keyword::class, 'keywordable');
    }
```

Query

```
$products = Product::whereHasMorph(
                    'keywordable',
                    [Keyword::class],
                    function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
                        $query->where('slug',  $request->keyword);
                    }
                )->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keywordable isn’t a relantionship of your Product model.
You can search by keyword using `whereHas`method

**Using whereHas method**

```php
    $products = Product::wherHas( 'keywords', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('slug',  $request->keyword);
    })->get();
```

**Using whereHasMorph if you have other relationships**

```php
    $products = Product::wherHasMorph( 'keywords', [Keyword::class], function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('slug',  $request->keyword);
    })->get();
```